# jQuery IF / Else Statement

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I'm trying to run a check to see if the CSS 'display' property is set to "none" and if it is to slideDown the element "menuBK", otherwise to slideUp "menuBK" but I'm getting an error on my IF line.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#burger").click(function(){
        if $("#menuBK").css( "display", "none" ); {
            $("#menuBK").slideDown('slow');
            $('body').addClass('noscroll');
        } else {
            $("#menuBK").slideUp('slow');
            $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: give us a http://jsfiddle.net/

post the exact wording of the error message

Comment: Looking for `$("#menuBK").is(':hidden')` or `$("#menuBK").not(':visible')`?

Comment: I suspect your JavaScript console is trying to tell you about a syntax/parsing error.  You might want to take a look at it...

Comment: Why don't use just `slidetoggle` http://jsfiddle.net/qx826/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change `if $("#menuBK").css( "display", "none" );` to `if ($("#menuBK").css( "display")=="none")` ,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#burger").click(function(){
      if ($("#menuBK").css( "display")=="none") {
        $("#menuBK").slideDown('slow');
        $('body').addClass('noscroll');
    } 
    else {
        $("#menuBK").slideUp('slow');
        $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    } 
    }); 
});
```

or you can use jQuery `is()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#burger").click(function(){
      if ($("#menuBK").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#menuBK").slideDown('slow');
        $('body').addClass('noscroll');
    } 
    else {
        $("#menuBK").slideUp('slow');
        $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove ; after if and add ()

```
if ($("#menuBK").css( "display" ) == 'none') {
        $("#menuBK").slideDown('slow');
        $('body').addClass('noscroll');
    } 
    else {
        $("#menuBK").slideUp('slow');
        $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#burger").click(function(){
      if ($("#menuBK:visible").length == 0) {
        $("#menuBK").slideDown('slow');
        $('body').addClass('noscroll');
    } 
    else {
        $("#menuBK").slideUp('slow');
        $('body').removeClass('noscroll');
    } 
    }); 
});
```